# How do I create a nested loop that emulates a grid of 100 rows and 10 columns in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, nested, iteration

I am new to Javascript and am having a hard time with this.  The numbers count up to 100 rows and is supposed to count over 10 colums.  I can only get the columns to count downward on the page, and not across like I want. Now, the column numbers are reading as odd numbers instead of in sequence.  I have no idea how I caused this to happen.  The column numbers should be from 1 to 10 and read down the page 100 rows. Please help! Thank you so much, in advance!

```
  var RowNum = 1;
  var ColNum = 1;

  for(RowNum=1; RowNum<=100; RowNum++)
for(ColNum=1; ColNum<=10;ColNum++)
  {
  document.write("RowNum: " + RowNum + " " + "Column: " + ColNum + "</br>");
  RowNum++;
  ColNum++;
   }
   while
   (RowNum <=100);
RowNum = RowNum + 1;
   while
    (ColNum<=10);


ColNum = ColNum + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(RowNum=1; RowNum<=100; RowNum++)
for(ColNum=1; ColNum<=10;ColNum++)
{
  document.write("RowNum: " + RowNum + " " + "Column: " + ColNum + "</br>");
  //RowNum++;  remove this
  //ColNum++;  remove this
}
```

The odd numbers problem is caused by this " ColNum++ ", ColNum is a 'for' loop variable and will increment every time , then in the same turn you are increasing it by 1 which will make the line

```
document.write("RowNum: " + RowNum + " " + "Column: " + ColNum + "</br>");
```

apply only for odd numbers

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: your error is putting `RowNum++;` and `ColNum++;` inside the for; remove them and it will work.

Try this:

```
  var maxRow = 100;
  var maxCol = 10;
  for (var i = 0; i < maxRow; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < maxCol; j++) {
          document.write("RowNum: " + i + " " + "ColNum: " + j + "</br>");
      }
  }
```

Because first, you don't need to add `RowNum++;` and `ColNum++;` inside the loop, it's already here: `for(RowNum=1; RowNum<=100; RowNum++)`. Next, isn't

```
while
   (RowNum <=100);
RowNum = RowNum + 1;
```

equivalent to `RowNum+=100;` ? (But much faster)
And finally it still doesn't do `RowNum+=100;` because you put `;` after the while.

Answer (score 0):

You make this easier I would suggest that you generate 2 or three columns and a couple of rows in HTML by hand so you can see what format you need to write out into the document.

Right now your're just spitting out 1000's of lines of text nodes with HTML breaks after them and there is no mark-up in this that will give you a row / column data layout. Until you know what your final HTML mark-up is supposed to look like you're not going to get very far.

Also your incrementing RowNum and ColNum inside the loops that are already incrementing them so that going to go horribly wrong. Look at what @Mageek has done with the two nested loops which is much simpler for you to understand, but still generates everything down the page.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is with a nested loop.  (A loop inside of another loop)  The first loop creates the TR element, while the second loop creates the TD elements for that row.

```
var rows=100;
var cols=10;

document.write("<table>");
  for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    document.write("<tr>");
      for (j=0; j<cols; j++) {
        document.write("<td>col"+j+"</td>");
      }
    document.write("</tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
```